# What implicit rule is causing GNU make to remove all files with pattern z%.h at the end of a build?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given *this* Makefile, for another project:

```
OBJDIR = .objs
OUTFILE = simplesale

CFILES = \
    manager.c \
    zresources.c

UIFILES = \
    addremovemoney.ui \
    employeeeditor.ui \
    itemeditor.ui \
    logviewer.ui \
    manager.ui \
    othersettings.ui

HFILES = \
    simplesale.h \
    $(UIFILES:%.ui=z%.h)

OFILES = $(CFILES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
PKGS = gtk+-3.0

xCFLAGS = \
    --std=c99 \
    -Wall \
    -Wextra \
    -Wno-unused-parameter \
    `pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS)` \
    $(CFLAGS)

xLDFLAGS = \
    `pkg-config --libs $(PKGS)` \
    $(LDFLAGS)

$(OUTFILE): $(OFILES)
    $(CC) -g -o $(OUTFILE) $(OFILES) $(xLDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(HFILES) dirs
    $(CC) -g -o $@ -c $< $(xCFLAGS)

zresources.c: gresources.xml $(UIFILES)
    glib-compile-resources --target $@ --generate-source $<

z%.h: %.ui
    go run tools/ui2cdecl.go $< $@ /simplesale/$<

dirs:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) z*
```

running `make` with no arguments does

```
mkdir -p .objs
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go addremovemoney.ui zaddremovemoney.h /simplesale/addremovemoney.ui
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go employeeeditor.ui zemployeeeditor.h /simplesale/employeeeditor.ui
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go itemeditor.ui zitemeditor.h /simplesale/itemeditor.ui
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go logviewer.ui zlogviewer.h /simplesale/logviewer.ui
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go manager.ui zmanager.h /simplesale/manager.ui
go run tools/ui2cdecl.go othersettings.ui zothersettings.h /simplesale/othersettings.ui
cc -g -o .objs/manager.o -c manager.c --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` 
glib-compile-resources --target zresources.c --generate-source gresources.xml
cc -g -o .objs/zresources.o -c zresources.c --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` 
cc -g -o simplesale .objs/manager.o .objs/zresources.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` 
rm zaddremovemoney.h zothersettings.h zemployeeeditor.h zmanager.h zitemeditor.h zlogviewer.h
```

Notice how GNU make decided to add a rule at the end that isn't in my Makefile to remove the `z%.h` files that were generated from the various `.ui` files (the `z%.h: %.ui` rule above).

What implicit rule is causing this one to happen? I tried `make -p -f/dev/null` but didn't find anything relevant. I know my `clean` rule will remove these files anyway; I'd rather only have them remove when explicitly `make clean`ing. (I'm starting to get a bit concerned by all the implicit rules...)

This is GNU make 4.0 on Ubuntu GNOME 14.10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` deletes intermediate build products by default. You need to mark your `z%.h` targets as precious if you want to keep them around:

```
.PRECIOUS: z%.h
```

Check out [**Chains of Implicit Rules**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) in the manual.

Comment: That did it; thanks! (I will never fully understand (GNU) make...)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. This particular behaviour is one of the weirder corners of the system.